# How many distinct active users did I have on a 90 day window?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a complex problem that seems to be trivial at first sight:

- for a given 90 day window, how many distinct active users did I have?

The table I will use to query this is the login table (hosted in Redshift), and it has a timestamp with the logintime and usertoken as the user identifier.

Whenever I want to answer this for a single day, the query is easy and straightforward:

```
select count (distinct usertoken)
from logins
where datediff('d',logintime,getdate()) <= 90
```

The problem becomes complex because I want to have this in a table with the number for every given date.

```
07/07  100k
07/06  98k
07/05  99k
07/04  101k
```

(...)

Window functions do not help me because I need to count distinct, and this is not possible in a window function.

To my knowledge, there is no way to iterate in a SQL query.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Please elaborate on `every given date`. Do you pass lower and upper bound for the time range? Or an array of random dates? Can there be duplicate entries for a single user on the same day? How big is your table? Number of rows? Bytes per row / table definition.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial way is very computationally expensive:

```
select days.d, count(distinct l.userid)
from (select distinct date_trunc('day', logintime) as d
      from logins l
     ) days left join
     (select distinct userid, date_trunc('day', logintime) as d
      from logins
     ) l
     on datediff('d', l.d, days.d) between 0 and 89
group by days.d
order by days.d;
```

Comment: Don't you have to say `between 0 and 90` (or possibly even 89)? The difference could be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something but from what I understand this should do :

-- In SQL Server

> select cast(logintime As Date)  , count (distinct usertoken) from logins 
>   where datediff(D,logintime,getdate()) <= 90 Group by
>   cast(logintime As Date)

in PostGreSQL 
Change cast(logintime As Date)  to trunc_Date(Day, logintime ) 
and datediff(D,logintime,getdate()) to datediff('d',logintime,getdate())

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that if a day has zero users logging in you don't mind not showing it in the list.

First we get a set of all the days we care about and call that set "days".

```
  with days as (
     select date_trunc('day', date) as day from logins
     where date > now() - '90 days'::interval
     group by day 
    )
```

Then we join the days set with the logins.

```
select day, count(distinct userid)
from days
join  logins on date_trunc('day', logins.date) = days.day
group by day
order by day
```